# Code works on react-router-dom 4.3.1 but not on 5.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

tl;dr: code below does not work on `5.2.0` version of `react-router-dom` but works on `4.3.1`

Context: I was tinkering around with some client-side-routing code online using [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-ve9v3?file=/StyledMenuItem.jsx) specifically utilizing the `react-router-dom` module. Below is some relevant snippets of the App:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import StyledMenuItem from "./StyledMenuItem";

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StyledMenuItem component={Link} to={"/hello"}>
        <span>Hello Link</span>
      </StyledMenuItem>

      <br />
      <br />

      <Link to={"/world"}>World Link</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

**StyledMenuItem.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class StyledMenuItem extends Component {
  render() {
    let WrapperComponent = this.props.component;
    if (WrapperComponent === undefined) {
      WrapperComponent = React.Fragment;
    }

    return (
      <WrapperComponent {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</WrapperComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, I was tinkering around & trying to imitate the behavior of the `component` prop of the [MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) API of the Material-UI.

The issue that had me puzzled: The `Link` that goes `to` '/hello' did not work on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-ve9v3?file=/StyledMenuItem.jsx) but **it worked on my local environment**. I am using the same exact code with the same versions of `react` & `react-dom` which is `16.13.1`.

**Upon my investigation**: I am not updated on my `react-router-dom` on my local environment. On the CodeSandBox, I was using `react-router-dom 5.2.0`; on my local environment I am using `react-router-dom 4.3.1`

So for that, back on CodeSandBox I tried testing it on the different versions (CodeSandBox has a cool feature that enables you to change package versions).
[image]

I've tested it on both versions & I can confirm that this issue definitely has something to do with my package versions.
Now, my question: what was the code change on the `react-router-dom 5.2.0` package that stopped supporting my code which is working on `react-router-dom 4.3.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily compare the source code, but with just a quick glance at your code my guess it is something to do with the extra props you also pass along to the `Link`. If you destructure `component` out of the props then it appears to work in your sandbox.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class StyledMenuItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { component, ...rest } = this.props; // <-- destructure and pass on the rest

    let WrapperComponent = component;
    if (WrapperComponent === undefined) {
      WrapperComponent = React.Fragment;
    }

    return <WrapperComponent {...rest}>{this.props.children}</WrapperComponent>;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Wrapping Link and passing props.]